# How to say something is not unusually x

Tags: grammar, words, usage

In the case in question, my intention is to say that something is good, but isn't unusually delicious.

My attempt has been

> いい味がしますが、非常に美味しいじゃありません。

My concern is that I've made an error in the second part in saying 美味しいじゃありません　rather than 美味しくない.

Is this right, and if not, what is a correct and natural way to say it instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> いい味がしますが、非常に美味しいじゃありません。

「おいしいじゃありません。」 (i-adjective + じゃありません。 / じゃないです。) sounds ungrammatical (even though you can say 「おいしいじゃありませんか！」「おいしいじゃないですか！」 "It's good, isn't it?" / "Isn't it good?").

I think you could say more like:

> ｛いい味**は**しますが、 / 味はいいですが｝、非常においしい｛というわけでは / というほどでは / というほどでも｝ありません。

Alternatively, I think you could also say:

> - まあ普通においしい｛けど / ですが｝、ものすごくおいしい｛というわけでは / というほどでも｝ありません。
> - まあまあおいしい｛けど / ですが｝、｛びっくりするほど* / 驚くほど｝おいしい｛というわけでは / ということは｝ありません。
> - 普通においしい｛けど / ですが｝、びっくりするほど*ではありません。

etc...
<sub>*びっくりするほど would sound casual and colloquial.</sub>

Comment: きれいにまとめはるわぁ。熟年の技やな。

Comment: ^ 誰が熟年やねん！ ほめたいんかかけなしたいんかわからんっちゅーねんｗ

Comment: どっちやったか覚えてへんわ。古いコメに反応するなっちゅうねん。

Comment: おや？タグ付けしてないのにお知らせ行くんだー