# Is there some difference between びっくりする and 驚く besides casual/formal?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-usage

Sorry for the "what is the the difference" question, but my usual sources didn't give me a satisfactory answer (「同じです。」...).

From the ways I've seen them used, there seems to be some difference in meaning though.

My understanding is that びっくり implies a sudden surprise like a jumpscare, whereas 驚く is a more "calm" surprise, as in "I am surprised that X is the case".

Am I reading too much into the usage here?

What confuses me though is 「驚いて飛び上がる」 (Though I can see why 「びっくりして飛び上がる」 would sound somewhat redundant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

びっくりする is more informal and sounds more casual/colloquial than 驚く.

Related:

- [How to say "surprising" in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17533/9831) `びっくりする: (verb) Be surprised. informal, but not a dialect.`
- [How to say something is not unusually x](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24989/9831) `びっくりするほど would sound casual and colloquial.`

---

> What confuses me though is 「驚いて飛び上がる」 (Though I can see why 「びっくりして飛び上がる」 would sound somewhat redundant).

びっくりして飛び上がる doesn't sound redundant to my native ear.  びっくりして飛び上がる sounds more casual and colloquial than 驚いて飛び上がる. I would expect to see/hear 驚いて飛び上がった in writing or formal speech, and びっくりして飛び上がった in daily conversation.

Comment: I see. So you would say they mean exactly the same?

Comment: @Garbaz 意味は同じです。少なくとも現代日本語では。In modern Japanese, they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to dictionary.goo.ne.jp

Definition of びっくり
１ （「吃驚」「喫驚」とも当てて書く）突然のことや意外なことに一瞬おどろくさま。「急に肩をたたかれてびっくりする」

２ わずかに動くさま。びくり。多く、否定の語を伴って用いる。
「―ともする若衆ぢゃあねえ」〈伎・名歌徳〉

Translation!

１To be surprised from unexpected or sudden things for an instant.

２ To barely move (Move just a little). Commonly accompanied with the negative form.

Examples: [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/びっくり/#je-103152](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%B3%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A/#je-103152)

Definition source: [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/びっくり/#jn-185375](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B3%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A/#jn-185375)

Definition of 驚く

［動カ五（四）］《意識していなかった物事に、はっと気づく意が原義》

１ 意外なことに出くわして、心に衝撃を受ける。びっくりする。感嘆する。「宇宙の神秘に―・く」「父の博識に―・く」

２ はっと気がつく。
「ほととぎすけさ鳴く声に―・けば君に別れし時にぞありける」〈古今・哀傷〉

３ 目が覚める。
「あまたたび言ふ声にぞ―・きて見れば」〈枕・八〉

(To suddenly realize something that the speaker was not conscious)

１To encounter with something unexpected, to receive a shock in heart. To be surprised (びっくり). To admire.

２Sudden realizing.

３To wake up (Open eyes)

Examples: [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/驚く/#je-8753](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E9%A9%9A%E3%81%8F/#je-8753)

Definition source: [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/驚く/#jn-32198](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A9%9A%E3%81%8F/#jn-32198)

Almost the same thing.

As I can see 驚く has negative connotations as well, you are surprised at something that is not subjectively good.

Comment: Your example links seem to be broken

Comment: Thank you! These definitions seem to line up with my understanding, at least in the different nuances. 驚く just is a bit broader than I thought (encompassing びっくり).

Comment: I fixed the links, thank you

Comment: You should notify that the latter two are an obsolete meaning.

Comment: @user4092 Which two do you mean exactly? (2) & (3) in the definition of 驚く?

Comment: @Garbaz (2) in びっくり and (2)&(3) in 驚く are obsolete.